# When I resize browser window the entirely HTML content has been shifted

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

We develop a website using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org), but in some pages when I resize browser window, the entirely html content has been shifted to right. How can I find the source of this problem. Anybody knows when this problem occurred?

[image]

and when I inspect html content saw this:

[image]

Comment: can you share the link of the website?

Comment: @Owais for see the website you must be login and I haven't access to give a username and pass to you, I'm so sorry. But I'll try to do this for you.

Comment: Ok no problem. Cant do much without seeing your code and working example